# ADD and REMOVE button function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create function for both ADD and Remove in a single button.

Default the inner text is select only after one click the button it should be replaced 'Remove'. It should be toggle function like. Please advise how to go ahead.

Jquery:

```
$('.lgi_btn_cta_toggle').on('click', function(){
    $(this).html('Selected').attr('id', 'Ctabutton-selected').append("<span class='lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected'></span>").addClass('tested').addClass('lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected-hover');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" target="_top" class="lgi_btn_cta_toggle clearboth tested lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected-hover" data-upc-tooltip-type="none" title="">Select<span class="lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected"></span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 8px 46px;
}
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle > span:after {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 13px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lgi_btn_cta_toggle {
  color: #5a9996;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #5a9996;
}
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle.disabled,
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle[disabled] {
  color: #c2c2c2;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c2c2c2;
}
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle:hover,
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle:focus,
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle:active {
  color: #5a9996;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #5a9996;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding: 8px 44px;
}

.lgi_btn_cta_toggle {
  padding: 8px 46px;
}
.tested{
padding: 8px 54px 8px 15px !important;
}
.tested:hover{
padding: 8px 50px 8px 13px !important;
}


a span.lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected {
    min-width: 43px;
    height: 45px!important;
    background: #5a9996;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 18px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
a span.lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected:focus, span.lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected:active {
    min-width: 43px;
    height: 43px!important;
    background: #5a9996;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 18px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
a span.lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected-hover {
    min-width: 43px;
    height: 43px !important;
    background: #5a9996;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 18px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle-selected:after {
  font-family: "MaterialIcons";
  content: "\e876";
            color: #ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
}
.lgi_btn_cta_toggle > span:after {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 13px !important;
    height: 15px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JasperZelf mentions - this sequence seems wrong - but in the interest of answering what you have asked for - I have amended my answer so the button click toggles between the three states (select / selected / remove). This is done by applying an incrementing value to the button and then using the modulus operator to determine the value from an array of the three options and then applying that as the text of the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var textOptions = ['Select','Selected','Remove'];


  $('#btnToggle').click(function(){
    var index = parseInt($(this).val())+1;
    var textOption = textOptions[index % 3];
    $(this).text(textOption).val(index);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnToggle" value="0">Select</button>
```

Comment: Actually, the button have 'select' text before clicking the button. If i'm click the 'select' button it should be replaced selected and again I'm clicking the 'selected' button it should be replaced 'remove' in the button.

Comment: ok - i understand - you want the sequence to be select - selected - delete..... but that is different to what you asked for in your post - you wanted to toggle between select and remove. which is what i provided

Comment: Absolutely correct, I meant similarly toggle function. Please advise.

Comment: I see you want the sequence "select - selected - delete".
I don't know the details of your application, but to me that sequence sounds a bit off.
Select and delete show intent, selected shows a state.
Step 1: I click select -> item becomes selected. 
Step 2: Why would I click selected? And if I do the button changes into delete...

Comment: As @JasperZelf mentions - this sequence seems wrong - but in the interest of answering what you have asked for - I have amended my answer so the button click toggles between the three states (select / selected / remove). This is done by applying an incrementing value to the button and then using the modulus operator to determine the value from an array of the three  options and then applying that as the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

As OP commented in @gavgrifs answer, he wants the button text sequence to be:  select - selected - delete. 
Sounds unlogical, but the following code acomplishes this and has room to do whatever extra actions you need to take on each button click.

Added advantage is that you can add slightly different styling to each button style. For example make the delete red.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.prodBtn').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('select')){
      $(this).removeClass('select');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      // do whatever you want on select
    }else if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('delete');
      // do whatever you want on selected
    }else if($(this).hasClass('delete')){
      $(this).removeClass('delete');
      $(this).addClass('select');
      // do whatever you want on delete
    }
  });
  
})
```

```css
.select:before {content: "Select"}
.selected:before {content: "Selected"}
.delete:before {content: "Delete"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Using the pseudo classes<br/>
<button type="button" class="prodBtn select"></button><br/>
<button type="button" class="prodBtn select"></button><br/>
<button type="button" class="prodBtn select"></button>
```